# emailing listboxitems by orders

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a listbox that gets its items from a filesystemwatcher. I want to be able to automatically email the items one by one every time an item is added to the listbox. Here's my code the problem is only the first item is getting emailed

```
Private Sub FileSystemWatcher1_Created(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles FileSystemWatcher1.Created
    If DeimosRadioButton1.Enabled = True Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(e.FullPath.ToString)
        Label2.Hide()
        If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
            Dim Counter As Integer = 0

            Dim Mail As New MailMessage
            Mail.Subject = "HACK REPORT!"
            Mail.To.Add("@gmail.com")
            Mail.From = New MailAddress("@gmail.com")
            Mail.Body = "Proof is attached in this email"

            Dim Attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment

                Attachment = New Attachment(ListBox1.Items(Counter).ToString)
                Mail.Attachments.Add(Attachment)



            Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            SMTP.EnableSsl = True
            SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Label4.Text, Label5.Text)
            SMTP.Port = "587"
            SMTP.Send(Mail)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: if you email the file name (`e.FullPath` - no need for ToString) before you add it to the listbox, you wont have to track anything.  The FSW runs on its own thread so you could send item #10 twice and #9 never.  As is, `Counter` is always going to be zero and send the first item

Answer (score 0):

As plutonix states your COUNTER never gets incremented because it is NOT in any form of FOR/NEXT or DO/LOOP

```
Private Sub FileSystemWatcher1_Created(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles FileSystemWatcher1.Created
'
If DeimosRadioButton1.Enabled = True Then
  ListBox1.Items.Add(e.FullPath.ToString)
  Label2.Hide()
  If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
    Dim Counter As Integer = 0
    For Counter = 0 to Listbox1.Items.Count - 1
      Dim Mail As New MailMessage
      Mail.Subject = "HACK REPORT!"
      Mail.To.Add("@gmail.com")
      Mail.From = New MailAddress("@gmail.com")
      Mail.Body = "Proof is attached in this email"
      '
      Dim Attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
      '
      Attachment = New Attachment(ListBox1.Items(Counter).ToString)
      Mail.Attachments.Add(Attachment)
      '
      Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
      SMTP.EnableSsl = True
      SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Label4.Text, Label5.Text)
      SMTP.Port = "587"
      SMTP.Send(Mail)
      'DoEvents/Yield system time to the sending or other events
    Next
  End If
End If
'
End Sub
```